# What kind of curve do these lines make?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections

Our teacher has given us a question to be solved.

What curve does the intersection points of the given lines make? A parabola, hyperbola, or none of them? (please look at the image I've posted. I am not speaking about all of the intersection points. Just the tangent curve beneath the lines)

the lines are as follows:

> $y=\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{5}x+\frac{41\sqrt{3}}{10}$
>
> $y=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{5}x+\frac{17\sqrt{3}}{5}$
>
> $y=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{5}x+\frac{29\sqrt{3}}{10}$
>
> $y=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5}x+\frac{13\sqrt{3}}{5}$
>
> $y=\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{2}$
>
> $y=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5}x+\frac{13\sqrt{3}}{5}$
>
> $y=-\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{5}x+\frac{29\sqrt{3}}{10}$
>
> $y=-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{5}x+\frac{17\sqrt{3}}{5}$
>
> $y=-\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{5}x+\frac{41\sqrt{3}}{10}$
>
> $y=\sqrt{3}x+5\sqrt{3}$
>
> $y=-\sqrt{3}x+5\sqrt{3}$

**my solution**: I tried to find if it is a parabola first. Assuming the maximum point to be $(0,\frac{13\sqrt{3}}{5})$ (the intersection point of $4$th and $6$th lines), I found the equation to be $y=-\frac{13\sqrt{3}}{125}x^2+\frac{13\sqrt{3}}{5}$. But after plotting it in [desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), the curve didn't meet the intersection points.

Then I tried to assume $(0,\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{2})$ as the maximum; I yielded $y=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{10}x^2+\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{2}$; but it again failed in plotting.

I then switched to hyperbola: After a long effort I found the equations to be $$\frac{(y-5\sqrt{3})^2}{(\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{2})^2}-\frac{x^2}{(\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{3})^2}=1$$ and $$\frac{(y-5\sqrt{3})^2}{(\frac{12\sqrt{3}}{5})^2}-\frac{x^2}{(\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{3})^2}=1$$ but I hink both of them are incorrect; because they are irrelevant to their asymptotes ($10$th & $11$th lines in the set of lines).

[line sets image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Ahw.png)

Sorry, I had to stretch the picture a little so that it better be displayed.

Comment: I am still not sure if those lines are asymptotes.

Comment: Can you/your teacher be more specific about which intersection points between which lines? If you have 11 non-parallel lines that gives you 110 different intersection points, which you can see on the graph. Doesn't make sense to talk about a degree 2 conic equation that satisfies 110 intersection points...

Comment: @SenZen Take a look at the image I've posted. There's a curve beneath the lines. you can also plot them in desmos to see yourself.

Comment: Are you sure you want a curve through all the intersection points and not just a curve that is tangent to all these lines?

Comment: @Klaus Not all the intersection points. the curve is obviously visible in the image I've posted

Comment: Once you've decided which points are the relevant ones - I would just use the fact that all conics are uniquely defined by 5 points. Or choose any 6 points and sub them into ax^2 + by^2 + cxy + dx + ey + f = 0 and solve the six linear equations for a, b, c, d, e, f.

Comment: @MathGeek Maybe you should start with formulating precisely what exactly you want because you are contradicting yourself. What you "see" in the image is clearly a parabola, but obviously this parabola does not go through any of the intersection points.

Comment: @MathGeek: It appears that you seek the curve that is the so-called ["envelope"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)) of the family of lines. An envelope isn't defined to go through intersection points of the lines; rather it's *tangent* to each of the lines, which agrees with this notion that it's the curve you "see" as more and more of those lines are drawn.

Comment: @Klaus the intersection points between (line 1 and line 2), (line 2 and line 3), (line 3 and line 4), (line 4 and line 5), (line 5 and line 6), (line 6 and line 7), (line 7 and line 8), (line 8 and line 9). these points make that curve

Comment: @Blue Thank you very much. Can you please explain more about it as the answer? I can't understand that Wikipedia article well. Just tell me about its equation and focus if can be measured.

Comment: @MathGeek: I agree that the Wikipedia entry is a bit opaque. A site search here for "envelope" may yield clear examples. That said, finding an envelope typically requires a formula for an infinite family of tangent lines, to which we apply some Calculus (which you may not be able to use). A mere finite list of lines only makes the problem *harder* and just-plain *tedious*. I'd have to ponder about the approach your instructor intends; maybe there's a neat trick here. ... Could it be that you aren't looking for the eqn at all, but are just supposed to graph and exclaim "Hey, neat! A parabola!"?

Comment: The only question that makes _mathematical_ sense is: what simple curve is tangent to all of these lines? Looking at the intersection points makes no sense. (Therefore, I suppose, the question as posed makes no sense.)

Comment: It is the parabola $y=-\frac{\sqrt 3}{10} \left(x^2-25\right)$ https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2vw0rvqkze

Answer (score 1):

Inspection shows that the given lines can be produced as follows:
$$y_k(x)={\sqrt{3}\over10}\bigl(2kx+(k^2+25)\bigr)\qquad(-5\leq k\leq 5)\ .\tag{1}$$One now should look for the [envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)) of the family $\bigl(\ell_c\bigr)_{c\in{\mathbb R}}$ of lines
$$\ell_c:\quad y-y_c(x)=0\ ,$$where the integer $k$ in $(1)$ has been replaced by the real parameter variable $c$.

Doing the standard calculations for finding the envelope one finds that the envelope $\epsilon$ of the line family $\bigl(\ell_c\bigr)_{c\in{\mathbb R}}$ is the parabola
$$\epsilon:\qquad y={\sqrt{3}\over10}(25-x^2)\ ,$$
plotted in red in the following figure.

Referring to these "standard calculations": When a family of curves in the $(x,y)$-plane is given by an equation of the form
$$F(x,y,c):=y-{\sqrt{3}\over10}\bigl(2c x+(c^2+25)\bigr)=0$$ then most points $(x,y)$ are "ordinary" points, meaning that there is no curve going through them, or that in the neighborhood of $(x,y)$ the curves are lined up like nice "parallel" stream lines. When $$F(x_0,y_0,c_0)=0\qquad\wedge\qquad F_c(x_0,y_0,c_0)\ne0$$ then $(x_0,y_0)$ is an "ordinary" point. When $$F(x_0,y_0,c_0)=0\qquad\wedge\qquad F_c(x_0,y_0,c_0)=0\tag{1}$$ then $(x_0,y_0)$ is a "special" point, since $c$, defined by $F(x,y,c)=0$,  is no longer a good function of $(x,y)$ in the neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$.

Some of the "special" points are indeed lying on an envelope $\epsilon$ of the given curve family. You obtain these "special" points by eliminating $c$ from the two equations $(1)$.

[image]

Comment: “Doing the calculations” — What calculations?

Comment: Please explain it. how did you conclude the envelope is a parabola with that function? With which calculations? in [Envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)) Wikipedia article I have found calculations for finding the envelope curve (starting with the equation: $$\frac{x}{t}+\frac{y}{11-t}=1$$ $11$ is just an example